# What is the difference between stochastic process and random variable?

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, random-variables, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-analysis

I am having a hard time grasping the core difference between a random variable and a stochastic process.

- A random variable assigns a number to every outcome of an experiment.
- A random process assigns a function of time to every outcome of an experiment.
  But the values of this function of time can be represented with ONE SINGLE random variable as well. So what is the point in having a stochastic process when you can represent an experiment with only random variables? Could somebody make one or two examples where the difference is clear?

Appreciate it

Comment: A random variable gives the outcome of a single experiment, say the roll of a die, or the temperature at noon.  A stochastic process can be a sequence of random variable, like successive rolls of the die in a game, or a function of a real variable whose value is a random variable, like the temperature throughout the day.

Comment: but why can i not use ONE SINGLE random variable to represent the temperature throughout the day? For instance a random variable X can be any temperature physically possible. Why can i not use X to represent the temperature throughout the day?Just measure the tempreature every minute, hour or seconds throughout the day and you will get the same result as the stochastic process?

Comment: How will you represent the temperature throughout the day with just one number?  There are infinitely many temperatures.  How do you distinguish the temperature at noon from the temperature at one o'clock?

Comment: By just letting X have those two temperatures?

Answer (score 5):

Given probability space $(\Omega, \mathfrak{B}, P)$ random variable is measurable map
$$X:\Omega \to \mathbb{R} $$
while random (i.e. stochastic) process is family of random variables
$$X:\Omega \times T \to \mathbb{R}$$
where under $T$ often is considered as time.

On example you can understand it so: random variable represent randomness when it do not depend on time. But if it depend?

Comment: Could you please explain it in a way so i can get an intuition. The definitions above doesnt make me any smarter.

Comment: @david harun. 1) The number of cars on the street is a random variable, but early in the morning this value has one distribution and during rush hour it will obviously have a different distribution
2) The number of people viewing this page at a given time is a random variable with one given density function for the distribution, but at another moment in time it may be another random variable with a different density for the distribution.
Answering your question - how do you describe such a situation with one random variable?
Write what you have doubt and I'll try to understand.

Comment: We can take the first example you took. We divide the day in 24 discrete hours and during each of these 24 hours we will have 24 random variables which form the stochastic process. During each hour you can have between 0 and ∞ cars in the street. Why cant i just let one random variable vary between 0 and ∞? I know that in every hour we will have different distributions but you could still get a distribution even if you let one random variable represent the entire day.

Comment: Let's take 2 different 1hour time length intervals. Suppose amount of cars have one density function for probability distribution in 1-st hour and another, different density function in second hour. How you describe it by one random value?

Comment: I dont know but if you take the entire day and then plot the number of cars in the street for each hour, you will have a graph where, during morning, midday and 15:00-16:00, you will have a spike (=large number of cars in the street) and during midnight for example we will have a minima in the graph. What distribution that is i dont know but its still a distribution?

Comment: Ok. When we take one random value $X$ and it gets one value $a$, then we know it's probability $P(X^{-1}(a))$ and it is fixed one number. Now I want describe situation where probability for this one given value of $X$ is one for some $t_1$ and another for $t_2$. It cannot be usual random value right?

Comment: i dont understand what you meanf you take a randome value of X in t_1 and in t_2 you might get different values (or the same). I dont see the problem.

Comment: Let's try go step by step: we have random value $X$ and it obtain some value $a$. To this value is corresponding some probability, so, if $A=X^{-1}(a)$ is preimage for  $a$, then we have fixed number P(A). Are you agree?

Comment: Yes. I get that every outcome of the random variable X has a probability P(.)  related to it. Even if i dont understand what preimage is.

Comment: Preimage of $a$ is all such elements from probability space, set $A$, which maps by $X$ to $a$, so for any $\omega \in A$ we have $X(\omega)=a$. Now imagine that probability for given fixed outcome is changing: in $t_1$ time it's differ from $t_2$ time moment. Suppose you roll die - usually probability to obtain one fixed number is fixed and is $\frac{1}{6}$, but imagine, that each time you roll die this probability is changing. Now more clear?

Comment: So a stochastic process is a series of random variables (discrete or continuous) indexed by time and these random variables may have different distributions from each other?How do we determine what kind of process we are dealing with? (i mean if its poisson, gaussian, markov etc.)

Comment: Yes. General name is "family" for discrete or continuous both. And how to determine which one is in each given case is very general task. But different one from definition process itself. What is stochastic process, hope, now is more clear?

Comment: yes. It is a bit more clear. I think i was overthinking a little bit. Thanks a lot for your time.

Comment: It's normal in mathematics. Feel free to ask when/if you'll need it.

Comment: I am also into the same thoughts and still I have some concerns. For example, given a process $X(t)$, then if I stop the time at $t=\bar t$ I have a random variable $X(\bar t)$. What is $E[X(\bar t)]$? The expected value makes sense for a run of experiments... so you need a number of realizations of that random variable that in turn it is a process. Isn't it?

Comment: From time point view random variable gives numeric values not dependent on time. For example we can imagine some fixed(finished) experiment. Expected value also becomes fixed, not dependent on time.

Comment: I think I am mixing up proability and statistics. The expected value considers the realizations of ALL the possible outcomes. When we have only the realizations of an experiment, that can be a time-series, at most we can compute the mean value of that time-series. But then, given a time-series, how can I distinguish if it represents the realizations of ONE random variable or if it is generated by the realizations of a sequence of different random variables? Also, a sequence of realizations of the same random variable can be named white noise if it meets some properties?

Comment: I agree with view on process as serialization of "one" random variable. Distinguish we can only by existence of time variable, because, of course, exists static processes. And yes for last question.

Answer (score 5):

You say, "A random process assigns a function of time to every outcome of an experiment."  No.  A random process could be a function of time.  At every time, the value is a random variable.  I'll give two examples, one where the process domain is discrete, and one where it's continuous.

First, consider a gambler who repeatedly plays a game, which he wins with probability $p<\frac12$.  If he wins, he gains one dollar, otherwise he loses one dollar.  He continues until he runs out of money.  Let $X_n$ be the gambler's bankroll after $n$ plays, where his initial bankroll is $X_0=B$ for some positive integer $B$.  We can say that once the gambler runs out of money, his bankroll is always $0$, so that $X_n$ is defined for every $n\geq 0$.  Each $X_n$ is a random variable.  For example, $X_1$ is $B+1$ with probability $p$ and $B-1$ with probability $1-p$.  The whole sequence $$X=X_0,X_1,X_2,\dots$$  is a stochastic process.  (Obviously, $X$ depends on $B$ and I should really write $X(B)$ or something like that, but I suppress that.)

Here's an example of a continuous domain.  Let $Y(t)$ be the temperature in a specific location on a summer day, where $t=0$ is midnight, and $t=24$ is midnight the following day.  Then $Y(t)$ is a random variable, for every $)\leq t\leq24$.

I'm not sure I understand what's giving you difficulty, but you may be confusing a random variable and its value.  It's true that if we take frequent readings of the temperature, we can make a graph showing what the temperature was throughout the day, but those are the values, not the random variables themselves.  For example, we may find that the temperature at noon was $85^\circ$F, but that doesn't mean $Y(12)$ is the number $85$.  $Y(12)$ is a random variable, distributed according to the probability distribution at that location in the summer.  $Y(12)$ tells us things like, "The temperature at noon will be between $80$ and $90$ degrees with probability $.65$."

Answer (score 1):

A stochastic process is a family of random variables indexed by some set, usually $\mathbb{Z}^{n}$ or $\mathbb{R}^{n}$.

It's additional structure over random variables that let you establish notions of trajectories, association over a space and other interesting properties.

In empirical studies, the set may represent discrete time ($\mathbb{Z}$), continuous time ($\mathbb{R}$), geographical location in a map on a given discrete time ($\mathbb{R}^2 \times \mathbb{Z}$) and et cetera.

Answer (score 0):

The point is to give more information in the behaviour of your experiment. For instance if you want to describe the market value of cookies --which behaves randomly because you can't describe each actor from such market-- you could describe the law of such market value at a given time, which would certainly be some Gaussian law, and with enough effort you could even see how this law depends on the time.

**BUT** even if you were able to give the law of the price **at each given time** you wouldn't make the difference between a market value stabilizing around a fixed mean (Ornstein-Uhlenbeck process) and a dumb monkey choosing randomly at each time the price of all cookies in the world (Gaussian white noise), because your information won't describe the way the price of cookies at time $t$ influences the price at time $s>t$. It would be hidden in the coupling of your laws.

The origin of studying the stochastic processes (instead of simple random variable) comes from this need to carry the influence from the past in order to describe all the history of your experiment, and not just its value. In a sense it's the same logical step as getting from "your position is just a number (or a point in space) which I can give" to "your position is a certain function of time, thus I also get your speed, your acceleration, etc".

Comment: Ok, but then if X at time t and and time s have the same distribution but are uncorrelated, then we don't need a stochastic process to describe a phenomenon, it is enough to observe the realizations of the same random variable at different time instant, isn't it?

Answer (score -1):

A random process is a *function*, for instance a random walk over the plane.

A random variable has a *value*, for instance the average distance of the random walk after a specified number of steps.